# Any gotchas using high side side load switches to drive other load switches?

Tags: microcontroller, load, high-side

I want to make a power distribution board using high side load switches, something like this Infineon product: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/infineon-technologies/BTS6143DAUMA1/1281799

The switches will be controlled with a standard MCU like an Arduino. Any gotchas with nesting them like the topology in my diagram?

[image: load switches]

Comment: Well, just do it that way. You need a FET or NPN to drive the inverted enable input of a BTS6143, it has a current source inside coming from Vbb (12 V in your case) and cannot be connected to an MCU directly. Do you have inductive loads? They need special care.